# c# using statement and StreamWriter

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I am using a `StreamWriter` to write things into notepad. And I discover if I am not using statement and instance the `StreamWriter` alone. The method is unable to run. Does anybody know the reason?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //StreamWriter c = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\rxxx\Desktop\important.txt", true);
        using (StreamWriter c = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\important.txt", true))
        {
            c.WriteLine("hello");
        }
```

This can be run. But if I run the remarked part instead. The Notepad shows nothing.

Anybody knows the reason?

Comment: Thanks all!!! You guys are very helpful. The Msdn's english is too hard and concise for me. It is so nice to seek help here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because when you use object in **using** which is good practice, it calls Dispose method and in the case of StreamWriter it call Fush on object as well which causes data to be written in file. you could write your code like this:

```
var c = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Test\important.txt", true);
c.AutoFlush = true;
c.WriteLine("hello");
c.Dispose();
```

Comment: Either `c.AutoFlush = true;` once in the beginning or `c.Flush();` after every write operation.

Answer (score 1):

```
StreamWriter c = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\rxxx\Desktop\important.txt", true);
// you need to write something to see 
c.WriteLine("hello");
```

if you use [**`using`** statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) it will dispose `StreamWriter` object automatically. But when you not having using statement you need to manually do the dispose of `StreamWriter` object. In that case also make sure even on exception case you are disposing object correctly. so you can do as below

```
StreamWriter c =null;
try
{
  c = new StreamWriter(fileFullPath, true);
  c.WriteLine("hello");
}
finally
{
  if (c!= null)
      c.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use using statement, the program does not flush the data from the buffer into the file. That's why "hello" is not written in the file when you open it in the notepad. You may explicitly flush the buffer in order to have your data written into the file:

```
 StreamWriter c = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\important.txt", true)
 c.WriteLine("hello");
 c.Flush();
```

However, you still need to dispose the stream. But if you use Dispose() method, it automatically flushes the buffer (by calling Flush() method) so you don't need to use Flush()!

By using 'using' statement, not only it flushes the buffer but also it release the stream appropriately and you don't need to write Dispose() explicitly. That's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

using statement is "ENSURE" the object in the scope will be Disposed [MSDN]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

```
using (StreamWriter c = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\important.txt", true))
{
  c.WriteLine("hello");
}
```

If you don't use using statement , I still recommended use try statement

```
try
{
  StreamWriter c = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\important.txt", true);
}
finally
{
  c.Close();
}
```