# System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, image, generics

I have a code that rotate image in my asp.net C# application
this is my code:

```C#
protected void ImgBtn180_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string vImageName = LblFarmId.Text;

        string vPath = "~/attachments/survey/" + vImageName + ".jpg";

        Image1.ImageUrl = vPath;

        //get the path to the image
        string path = Server.MapPath(vPath);

        //create an image object from the image in that path
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path);

        //rotate the image
        img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipXY);

        //save the image out to the file
        img.Save(path);

        //release image file
        img.Dispose();

        Random rnd = new Random();
        Image1.ImageUrl = vPath + "?" + rnd;

    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        LblCatchError.Text = ee.ToString();
    }
}
```

when I run it on the server, I'm getting sometimes the following error

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+. at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams) at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format) at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename)

and sometimes the following error

> System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory. at
>   System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename, Boolean
>   useEmbeddedColorManagement) at System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String
>   filename)

I read all articles and solutions about this error, and nothing worked. 
some said, "make sure that the desired folder has Read/Write permissions." 
it has permissions..

some said , "you must dispose image object to release the memory on the server." , 
I already have the code img.Dispose(); to release image file,

What might be the problem in the code? any advice?

Comment: [use a finally at the end of your try catch block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984336/net-using-using-blocks-vs-calling-dispose) or try a [using statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808753/right-way-to-dispose-image-bitmap-and-picturebox). I'm curious, what articles did you read on this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: so you think that I have to put it inside using? like this? ....
using (System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path))
                {
                    //rotate the image
                    img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipXY);

                    //save the image out to the file
                    img.Save(path);

                    //release image file
                    img.Dispose();
                }

Comment: this was example of bad solutions for the similar problem ........... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571022/how-to-find-reason-for-generic-gdi-error-when-saving-an-image

Comment: @lloyd Thx, I did what you told me to do, but still I have the same error

Comment: Using will call dispose. Please add code in the question. Very hard to read in comment

Comment: Try [StreamWriter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514530/c-sharp-using-statement-and-streamwriter) so you can write to the file.

Comment: @lloyd ,I changed this (Rotate180FlipXY) to (Rotate180FlipNone) and after that the problem has been solved, it is really strange, I still don't know why Rotate180FlipXY only on 180 degree causes this problem, if I change the degree to 270 it will work fine, but Rotate180FlipXY causes this strange error, thanks anyway for effort

Comment: no problem. maybe post the answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

I changed this (Rotate180FlipXY) to (Rotate180FlipNone) and after that the problem has been solved